# How to concatenate 2 jquery functions that do the same with an OR operator?

Tags: jquery, operators

Hi,

I have 2 functions that do the exact same thing:

```
 $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
   sendmessage();
 });
 
 ///second function 
 $("#usermsg").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {  
    console.log(e.shiftKey ? 'Shift & Enter' : 'Enter only')
    if (!e.shiftKey) {
     sendmessage();
    }
  }
});
```

I want to save as much code as possible so I would prefer something like "if this function OR this function". Something like this:

```
 if $("#submitmsg").click || $("#usermsg").keypress(13) && !13.shiftKey {
  sendmessage();
 }
```

but I cant get the syntax right. How is it done?

Thank you.

Comment: That is pretty efficient already. Although there are ways with maybe making an array of event details and looping through that array binding each one to the appropriate thing, that would likely result in more code in the end for such a basic use case.

Comment: `I want to save as much code as possible`. There is a point where focusing too much on lowering the amount of code is actively harmful to a project. Seems like you are at that point.

Comment: *"How is it done?"* - It isn't.  The code is already correct.  The only "same thing" these event handlers do is already encapsulated in a function called `sendmessage`, which they both call.  Everything else about them is not the "same thing".

Comment: If they were both the same selector they could be combined but require conditional to check which event occurred also. I agree that what you currently have is clean , readable & maintainable code and trying to get tricky with it will not be as developer friendly in the long term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the anonymous function as your `click` handler as it's doing nothing more than passing the call to `sendmessage()`. Just pass the `sendmessage` function reference directly as

```
$("#submitmsg").click(sendmessage);
```

Your second function cannot be combined with the first one as both the `id` selectors as well as the triggering events are different. But, you could slim it down to

```
$("#usermsg").keypress(e => {
  if (e.which == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    sendmessage();
});
```

unless the `console.log` call is important to you.

Comment: I did. I hope you can help me with my newest question as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you were probably wanting to try is combining multiple events with the same handler.

I don't think that is practical in the scenario shown since you have different selectors also and some conditional logic in one of the cases.

A very simple example of doing it with same selectors that checks the `event.type` is as follows:

```js
$('#test').on('focus input', function(e){
  console.log(`Event type= ${e.type}`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" placeholder="edit me"/>
```

Comment: okay, if you all say this is the shortest way possible then I will leave it as is.

Comment: You also need to balance brevity with readability. Getting cute with some code then coming back to it months later to modify it can sometimes be counter productive if it takes you a long time to sort out or refactor that "cute code"

Comment: There is also a practice of *don't over optimize*